# Unexpected behaviour from case statements

Tags: shell, switch-statement, ksh

I came across some behaviour of case statements that I don't understand..

```
case [1] in *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac
case $b[1] in *1*)echo 50;;*)echo 58;;esac
echo [1] | hexdump -C --
echo $b[1] | hexdump -C --
```

output:

```
50
58
00000000  5b 31 5d 0a                                       |[1].|
00000004
00000000  5b 31 5d 0a                                       |[1].|
00000004
```

b is a variable that hasn't been set. I want to know why these case statements produce different results despite the commands having the same hexdump when passed to echo.

Comment: this looks like a ksh bug to me.

Comment: @whjm not necessarily a bad thing. We used it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/127128#127128) to separate bash from ksh.